# JNI Calls different in C vs C++?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

So i have the following code in C that utilizes Java Native Interface however i would like to convert this to C++ but am not sure how.

```
 #include <jni.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "InstanceMethodCall.h"

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
 Java_InstanceMethodCall_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
     jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", "()V");
     if (mid == NULL) {
         return; /* method not found */
     }
     printf("In C\n");
     (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid);
 }
```

Java Program:

```
 class InstanceMethodCall {
     private native void nativeMethod();
     private void callback() {
         System.out.println("In Java");
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         InstanceMethodCall c = new InstanceMethodCall();
         c.nativeMethod();
     }
     static {
         System.loadLibrary("InstanceMethodCall");
     }
 }
```

What are the differences in which JNI interacts with C and C++? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Pete

Comment: What's wrong with the above? It looks like valid C++ code to me.

Comment: Upvoted because of the well-constructed example.  Nicely put.

Comment: Thank you for example on C in which I'm searching for. For C++, you can take a look at this example (although in SDL2) but will convey the usage https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AndroidGetActivity?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I used to have the book [Essential JNI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136798950). And while it is kinda dated (1998), much of it still works today.

If I recall correctly, in C, Java constructs are simply pointers. Thus, in your code, `(*env)->` is dereferencing pointers to give you access to the underlying methods.

For C++, `env` is actually an object – a different entity than a C pointer. (And JNI can actually provide real objects for your C++ code to manipulate, since C++ actually supports objects.) So `env->` has a different meaning in C++, it means "call the method that is contained in the object pointed to by `env`.

The other difference, I believe, is that many of the C-JNI functions require that one of your parameters be the `JNIEnv *env`. So in C you might have to say `(*env)->foo(env, bar)`. With C++, the second reference to `env` is not necessary, so you can instead say `env->foo(bar)`.

Unfortunately, I don't have the above book in front of me, so I can't quite confirm this! But I think investigating those two things (specifically looking for them on Google or in other JNI code) will get you pretty far.

Comment: So JNI can actually handle both C and C++? I didn't know that (but maybe that's not surprising, since I've never used JNI :p).

Comment: (haha, ty for fixing my markdown!)

Yep; the interface behaves the same way - the C vs C++ code is /basically/ isomorphic, and in practice the only difference is syntax.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference between JNI calls in C and CPP is this:

C-style JNI looks like
(*env)->SomeJNICall(env, param1 ...)

C++ style JNI looks like
env->SomeJNICall(param1 ...)

so to convert it to CPP you need to do

```
Java_InstanceMethodCall_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "callback", "()V");
    if (mid == NULL) {
        return; /* method not found */
}
printf("In C++\n");
env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid);
//rest of your code
```

Also, make sure that your JNI functions follow the naming convention.

Example:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_shark_JNITestLib_JNITestLib_startServer(JNIEnv* env, jobject o, jstring inputName, jstring streamName, jstring description) {
```

You can see that the convention is
Java_(package name) _ (classname) _ (methodname)

since the one above was used in a class like

```
package com.shark.JNITestLib

import java.util.stuff;

public class JNITestLib 
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("myJNIlib");
    }

    public native synchronized int startServer(String inputName, String streamName, String description);

//more class stuff...
}
```

When working with JNI i made it a convention to name the class containing JNI calls to be the same name as the package. Thats why you see JNITestLib twice (and thats why my JNI works right off the bat because I always forget how to properly name the JNI calls)

Cheers, hope I helped :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried wrapping your C code in an `extern "C"`.  See [C++ Faq Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) for more information, and for other possible mechanisms to let you use your C code with C++.

Comment: I think that's probably the issue. JNI expects C code, so he's probably getting linking errors.

Comment: Yarp. Names are probably getting mangled in the C++ compiler. Add the extern C { <your code> }.

Comment: Why would you want to wrap C++ code as C and use the ugly C syntax when you can use the more concise C++ syntax directly?

Comment: @rustyx: When porting code, one can choose to do a semantic port (retain semantics, but use language specific features and constructs) or a line-by-line port (change as little code as possible, mostly line-by-line rather than holistically).  A semantic port is easier to maintain and use.  A line-by-line port is easier to do and makes it easier to leverage any existing knowledge-base associated with the original code.  Mind you, a line-by-line port may introduce weird bugs if trying to port a construct to a language that doesn't really support it.

Comment: I'll also note that a line-by-line port, if it's obnoxiously easy (as was the case here), is a great way to offer a prototype to verify that the library being ported will be usable after it is ported.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I touched standard C++ but I'm gonna try it anyway.

"`(*env)->`" looks weird to me. Shouldn't that simply be "`env->`" ?

Maybe I'm wrong and it is supposed to work, but why make things more complicated anyways?

Comment: x->y is shorthand for (*x).y.  Therefore, (*env)->y is equivalent to (**env).y, which is different from (*env).y: there is an extra dereference occurring.

Comment: The dereference syntax, I actually knew. Let me be more clear: I'm just far from convinced the C++ version of JNIEnv actually requires the double dereferencing.

Comment: @michaelaubert See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077815/passing-env-as-first-argument-of-jni-functions?noredirect=1#comment118571626_67077815.