# BufferedImage image pointer data as a JNI parameter for C function

Tags: java, c, pointers, java-native-interface, bufferedimage

I'm developing a Java application that uses JNI (bridge to C dynamic/shared library).  In the Java side of the application, I am generating a series of images, and in the C code, I am encoding them into a video.

I know I could just save the images in a temporary file of some sort and pass the file path into C, but that seems hackish and slow.

Is it possible for me to get the BufferedImage RGB24 array data and pass that into C?

I am fairly new at Java and JNI.

Comment: Check this link: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html there's a section dedicated to arrays and JNI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is.

`jintArray` or `jbyteArray` is the structure you should use.

And if I remember correctly, there's `getRGB(...)` method of `BufferedImage` that returns an array of ints representing RGB values.

So, put those two together and you'll be on your way.

Refer to [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html) document for method signatures, etc.

Answer (score 4):

it's entirely possible to transfer byte[] from Java to C.

its actually simple but you really really need to watch your method signatures. looking for example code..

```
  JNIEXPORT jbyteArray passToC(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jbyteArray array)
  {
      int length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
      byte data[256];
      (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, array, 0, 256, data);
      //data should hold your bytes now.
  }
```

here's a useful link too http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

edit: but like i said, be very very careful about the method name, as it needs to have a package/class somewhere in it...

look at this one too, [JNI Calls different in C vs C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935379/jni-calls-different-in-c-vs-c/9095100#9095100)
 it'll shed great light on JNI as tutorials online never really seem to bring up the fact that **JNI IS DIFFERENT FOR C++ than C** clear enough...

Comment: Both yourself and AljoshaBre answered with essentially the same information, and unfortunately I can't choose both as the accepted answer, but I did want you to know that I found the information on here very helpful and complimentary to the other answer.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: thats cool, i don't really care much about the rep as long as you resolve your issue. thanks for marking this as 'helpful' though ;)