# Android JNI native C function call kills activity

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, native

What works:
I have a c executable that runs a TUN/TAP service, and two shell scrips (to configure the "ip route" and "iptables") that run fine in terminal, all run as root.

What doesn't work:
I am attempting to create an Android App to run the c executable and shell scripts after a button is pressed. I originally made it such that onClick would create a process with processBuilder as shown below:

```
final Button button1 = ...
...
public void onClick(View v) {
    String ip_address = edIPAddress.getText().toString();
    Process process;
    try {
        process = new ProcessBuilder()
            .command("/system/bin/su", "-c", "/data/tuntapserv/armeabi/mytunserv " + ip_address)
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .start();

        InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();

        pOutput.append("TUN/TAP IS CONFIGURED!\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();             
    }
}
```

To the best of my knowledge this should have worked fine, but in practice mytunserv would stop working after a random period of time. mytunserv would start my TUN/TAP but then when I went to check the "ip route" after several minutes, I would see the tun/tap has stopped and disappeared. Similarly I tried runtime.exec, even though this seems to use processbuilder, and had the same issue.

I then moved onto using threads instead of processes, and this seems to work fine for the shell scripts.

```
...
final Button button2 = ...
...
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sThread = new ScriptThread();
        sThread.start();
    }
...

    private class ScriptThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Process process;
            try {
                process = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .command("/system/bin/su","-c","/system/bin/sh /data/tuntapserv/armeabi/setup_ip.sh")
                    .redirectErrorStream(true)
                    .start();

                InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();

                pOutput.append("SCRIPT FINISHED!\n");

                while(true) {
                    Thread.sleep(0);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();             
            }
        }
    }
```

This seemed to work for the two shell scripts at least. I eventually gave up on this method for calling mytunserv thinking the process or thread must be getting killed by the java thread handler, which seems pretty unpredictable from my research. Instead I moved onto JNI, since this seems more suitable than hardcoding my the path to the c executables and shell scripts.

So this is my most recent issue, and what I am looking for help on.

Here is my JNI setup:

```
#include <jni.h>
...
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_android_1sp_1api_sample_SetupTunTap_runtun(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jstring ip_address)
{
    jchar *ip;
    jboolean iscopy;
    ip=(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, ip_address, &iscopy);
    ...
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, ip_address, ip);
    ...
}
...
```

The c code above turns into liblmytunserv.so.

```
package android_sp_api.sample;
...
public class SetupTunTap extends AnotherActivity {

    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("lmytunserv");
    }

    public native int runtun(String ip_address);
    ...

        final Button button1 = ...
    ...
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String ip_address = edIPAddress.getText().toString();

        SetupTunTap myTun = new SetupTunTap();

        myTun.runtun(ip_address);

        pOutput.append("TUN/TAP IS CONFIGURED!\n");
    }
...
```

From what I can tell, the c code should be able to call other functions in the c code that are not JNIEXPORT'ed. The JNIExport is just a way to have the Java code interact with the c code, from what I imagine.

Anyway, now my issue is that in debugging or running the app on the phone once I press button1 the activity closes and goes back to my main menu activity. In Debug it says ".... DalvikVM[localhost:8602]" and in DDMS the device stays "Online". The LogCat does not output any thing to suggest that the activity exited/crashed. And upon entering the SetupTunTap activity LogCat resumes by displaying information but never outputs anything when button1 is pressed and the screen flashes black and reverts to my main menu activity. Here is the part, in the LogCat, at which the liblmytunserv is loaded:

LogCat Output:

```
...

07-30 16:30:19.531: D/dalvikvm(4716): Trying to load lib /data/data/android_sp_api.sample/lib/liblmytunserv.so 0x41688d20

07-30 16:30:19.531: D/dalvikvm(4716): Added shared lib /data/data/android_sp_api.sample/lib/liblmytunserv.so 0x41688d20

07-30 16:30:19.531: D/dalvikvm(4716): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/android_sp_api.sample/lib/liblmytunserv.so 0x41688d20, skipping init
```

How do I debug further? If I set a breakpoint at "myTun.runtun(ip_address);" then I can see all the variables in the Debug interface on Eclipse. If I proceed past that point, the activity disconnects and I only see the .so lib file load in the LogCat. I would guess that my JNI setup must be wrong, so any advice anywhere in my thought process would be wonderful.

Hardware:
Samsung Galaxy Nexus v4.0.4 (Rooted)

Files:

- mytunserv = c exectuable
- setup_ip.sh = shell script
- setup_ip1.sh = shell script
- SetupTunTap.java
- liblmytunserv.so (placed in /libs/armeabi, /libs/armeabi-v7a, /libs/x86)

What I need:
The native "runtun" function in the C library liblmytunserv.so runs forever in a while(1) infinite loop. When the Java code calls the function (once button1 is pressed), I need the function to run forever. Shell scripts setup_ip.sh and setup_ip1.sh are run once the c executable is running. How do I get the c executable to run forever?

Let me know if you need more information, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JNI

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_android_1sp_1api_sample_SetupTunTap_runtun(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jstring ip_address)
```

in Activity

```
package android_sp_api.sample;
```

these need to match ;)

edit:
four out of five times it's just this. also, post the java side as well, but I hope it looks like

```
class SetupTunTap
{
   public native int runtun(String ip_address);
```

/// 
    }

so post SetupTunTap class as well\

edit2: whoopse, the edit was unneeded. it's just the package name.

Comment: According to a source I used for learning JNI, it seemed to suggest that I need to replace "." and underscores, with underscores and "_1" respectively.

Comment: did you test it? can you make a dummy printf function that says "hi" when you invoke it from java? the jni bridge is the first thing we need to get off the 'potential issue' checklist anyway as it's the most common root cause.

Comment: Present your "source for learning JNI" please, i am curious :)

Comment: I was gonna say "try it without the ones" but hey, i never use underscores in my package names. it could be legit.

Comment: http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/informant/index.html is my source for the escape characters in JNI. When I originally tried it with straight underscores it said something along the lines of invalid function name.

Comment: JNI/Delphi !??! theres this http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf and the short version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935379/jni-calls-different-in-c-vs-c/9095100#9095100

Comment: Page 152 of the document or 166 in that jni.pdf references those escape characters. :-\

Comment: If I did a printf "hi" where would the output go? Edit: working on it, I'll let you know :). Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: make it call android_log instead of printf? :)

Comment: I am taking back my pretentious comment. A simple one minute test really confirmed that javah creates "_1" for underscores. Thank you for opening yet another door in the JNI maze for me :)

Comment: So please let me ask yet another question. You expect the runtun native method to do what? Spawn the `mytunserv` process? Call the scripts? Do you need to do something in the while(1) loop or is that just some kind of desperate prevention of killing your process?

Comment: Sweet, that helped out a bunch. I can now get log messages from the native c function. I am going to shotgun log messages in it to see where it messes up. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: thats the spirit, printf debugging all the way.

Comment: @vtmarvin I want mytunserv to run forever once created (since it makes the tun or tap). The while(1) is me getting desperate in preventing the death of the process, I have since moved onto trying to get mytunserv to run via JNI. The scripts run fine via processbuilder (and only need to run once).

Comment: try to measure your up-time in while(1) and print it when the process dies. it might be valuable log data. for instance, you might notice that the process dies at similar intervals thereby possibly revealing a leak. a leak that valgrind can spot too.

Comment: Your debugging advice helped me solve the problem. I am grateful!

Comment: what exactly did you do to solve the problems @Markus was It the problem of your native part? I have a same problem. The Java Activity was shutting down when I make a call to native method in which implemented a while loop.

Comment: Your native methods should try to be ran asynchronously.