# JNI and C++ - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI successfully to call some C code, however when I want to change to C++ JNI throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` whenever I try to call a method.

This one works:

```
g++ -c -Icryptopp562 -O3 -fPIC -fpermissive CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.cpp
gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -O3 -shared -fPIC -o libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools.c CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.o -lcryptopp
```

With this one, I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`:

```
g++ -c -Icryptopp562 -O3 -fPIC -fpermissive CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.cpp
g++ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -O3 -shared -fPIC -fpermissive -o libCI3CppEncryptionTools.so de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools.cpp CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.o -lcryptopp
```

The generated header is as follows:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools */

#ifndef _Included_de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools
#define _Included_de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools
 * Method:    encrypt
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools_encrypt
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools
 * Method:    decrypt
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools_decrypt
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

And my implementation (.cpp) is as follows, I omitted the `decrypt` method:

```
#include <jni.h>

#include "CI3CppEncryptionToolsImpl.h"

#include "de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools.h"

jstring
Java_de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools_encrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring s) {

    return env->NewStringUTF(encrypt(env->GetStringUTFChars(s, JNI_FALSE)));

}
```

For the C version I simply write `return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, encrypt((*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, s, JNI_FALSE)));` instead.

The C version works, the C++ version fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: de.zdv.research.emdu.CI3CppEncryptionTools.encrypt(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In implementation (.cpp) you have written function  as

```
jstring Java_de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools_encrypt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring s){
       //---------
}
```

Please write it as

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_de_zdv_research_emdu_CI3CppEncryptionTools_encrypt
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring){
       //------------
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, and sadly it didn't work, as I understood `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` are macros to ensure the correct C binding... but I've seen examples where they were left out and it worked.

Comment: @yvesonline  The JNIEXPORT isn't the problem, the problem is your implementation arguments are not the same as your definition.  Your second argument should be a jclass, not a jobject, to match your static function's JNI definition.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I did not see that! That was exactly what was wrong. Thanks! I wonder why the C version worked this way...

Comment: I don't understand how can bad parameter type lead to `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. What am I missing?

Comment: @manuell  Please check the types of parameters passed to function

Comment: @rachana I thought extern "C" functions exported names were not decorated with arguments types. How bad types could lead to a link error?

Comment: @rachana The second comment says that a type should be a jclass, not a jobject. You seem to not understand my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile C++, you should have an `extern "C"` prefix before the functions declarations/definitions.

But there are others differences, see [JNI Calls different in C vs C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935379/jni-calls-different-in-c-vs-c)

Comment: Thanks! you are the first person that say this. Very helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure java can find your dynamic native library in the same directory where you launch the JVM.  Check also that your dynamic library is compiled for the same architecture as the JVM you are running your program with (for example, 32-bit for a 32-bit JMV, or 64 for a 64-bit JVM)

Comment: I call my Java application via `java -Djava.library.path=lib ...` to ensure that the library is found. The architecture matches, as I mentioned, the C version runs without any problems.