# Passing env as first argument of JNI functions

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

There seem to be two ways of using JNI functions that I've come across:
`(*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj)` and `env->GetObjectClass(obj)`. But the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetObjectClass) refers to only the former version with two parameters. Is this some fundamental concept of C++ that I'm unaware of, like how `self` is passed in Python implicitly?

Comment: Are you certain the type of `env` is the same in both instances?   The second variant has `env` available as `this`, exactly like implicitly passing self in python.

Comment: Yes, it's `JNIEnv *env` in both cases. I didn't know you could access the pointer in the arrow notation in C++ though.

Comment: The JNI documentation is written for C. The JNI interface is a little simpler in C++. `(*env)->` will compile only if `env` is declared as `JNIEnv**`. `env->` will compile if `env` is declared as `JNIEnv*`

Comment: `(*env)->GetObjectClass(env...` is for C code, `env->GetObjectClass` is for C++ code.

Comment: Thanks, @RemyLebeau and @rustyx. Now I know what to search for ("JNI C vs C++"), and I found similar questions. But `env` is declared as `JNI env*` even in [this](https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/java-native-interface-jni-example-65) C example.

Comment: @user15286099 look in `jni.h` and you will see that `JNIEnv` itself is declared as two different types in C and C++. In C, `JNIEnv` is a pointer to a struct. In C++, `JNIEnv` is an actual struct.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But what does it mean to dereference a struct (in both cases, after simplifying the arrow operator)?

Comment: @user15286099 In C, `JNIEnv *env` will declare `env` as a pointer to a pointer to a struct, hence the need to dereference twice, ie `(*env)->member` (aka `(*(*env)).member`). In C++, `JNIEnv *env` will declare `env` as a pointer to a struct, hence the need to dereference only once, ie `env->member` (aka `(*env).member`)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, right, I mixed up `JNIEnv` and `env`. Thanks a lot!