# Java, C++ JNI - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError : No .dylib in java.library.path

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I was trying to link java and c++ code using java JNI but when I ran the java file using dylib path, getting an error that no file was available. However, my lib file is available in the current working directory.

Also, I tried moving same dylib to `/Library/Java/Extensions` but still the same error.

Java File: JNIJava.java

```
public class JNIJava {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("JNI_CPP");
    }
    public native void printString(String name);
   
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        JNIJava jniJava = new JNIJava();
        jniJava.printString("Invoked C++ 'printString' from Java");
    }
}
```

Header file : JNIJava.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h"
/* Header for class JNIJava */

#ifndef _Included_JNIJava
#define _Included_JNIJava
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     JNIJava
 * Method:    printString
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIJava_printString
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C++ file : JNIJava.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "JNIJava.h"

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIJava_printString(JNIEnv *env, jobject jthis, jstring string) {
    const char *stringInC = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, NULL);
    if (NULL == stringInC)
        return;
    cout << stringInC << endl;
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, stringInC);
}
```

Used the below commands to link and run the code :

```
javac JNIJava.java -h .

g++ -dynamiclib -O3 \
    -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/include \
    -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/include \
    JNIJava.cpp -o JNI_CPP.dylib

java -cp . -Djava.library.path=$(pwd) JNIJava
```

When I Do ls :

```
JNIJava.class           JNIJava.cpp             JNIJava.h               JNIJava.java            JNI_CPP.dylib
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JNI_CPP in java.library.path: /Users/tkapadn/Documents/Documents_Data/Lens-Eclipse-Workspace/Java_JNI/CPP
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2447)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
        at JNIJava.<clinit>(JNIJava.java:3)
```

Here is the screenshot of the error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrkDV.png)

**Note - I tried linking c with java using JNI and I was successfully able to run the java file.**

Java Version - jdk1.8.0_261,
System - macOS Big Sur (11.6.1)

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: your `System.loadLibrary()` call is failing, it couldn't find the library.

Comment: However, after resolving that, you might still hit some UnsatisfiedLinkException problems because the name of the method looks... suspicious.
it might be needed to use `Java_com_example_jni_JNIJava_JNIJava_printString` instead.

Comment: changed the method names to `Java_JNIJava_printString` same as header file but still getting the same error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JNI_CPP in java.library.path: –` @Shark

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935379/jni-calls-different-in-c-vs-c/9095100#9095100)

The package name of your java class is important, because it dictates how the C method must be called. However I can't help you to resolve the "library file can't be found" issue, you'll have to fix that one yourself and figure out where it's actually looking for the `JNI_CPP` library.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also changed the library name to `JNI_CPP` while generating it and loading it in the java file. The lib file is available in the same directory not sure what is the problem with the lib not found issue. I have not used any package structure so everything is at the default level for the java class and the same is followed for the CPP method naming @Shark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using 'System.loadLibrary("")' use  'System.load("lib path")' and check if the library is working.then you can move it to the java library path.

for example : (tested and working)

```
try { 

String libPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + System.mapLibraryName("JNI_CPP"); 
System.load(libPath); 

} catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your suggestion. It's working with both load() and loadLibrary() function. I figured out that when lib get created somehow it appends the lib keyword. In this case, lib was created after command `g++ -dynamiclib` with the name 'JNI_CPP' but somehow it was referring 'libJNI_CPP'. So what I did, in load/loadLibrary function I provided the name 'JNI_CPP' but in `g++ -dynamiclib` I provided the lib name as 'libJNI_CPP' and it worked. Yeah but your load method helped me to debug the actual issue.@stark9000, @Botje

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `System.loadLibrary` must omit the `lib` part of the filename:

```
        System.loadLibrary("JNI_CPP");
```

Your cpp file should match the headerfile, so remove the `com_example_jni_` part of your function name.

Comment: I tried removing the lib part from the filename: 
`System.loadLibrary("JNI_CPP")` and changed the method names to `Java_JNIJava_printString` same as header file but still getting the same error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JNI_CPP in java.library.path:` @Botje

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72358922/edit) with the new situation and proof that `libJNI_CPP.dylib` exists at the path you point `java.library.path` to.

Comment: I have edited the question with suggestions provided(method name change and remove the lib part from loadLibrary function) by you and attached the screenshot of the path to point `java.library.path`. Even I checked the permission of the lib file. @Botje

Comment: Thanks for providing your suggestion. It's working with both load() and loadLibrary() function. I figured out that when lib get created somehow it appends the lib keyword. In this case, lib was created after command `g++ -dynamiclib` with the name 'JNI_CPP' but somehow it was referring 'libJNI_CPP'. So what I did, in load/loadLibrary function I provided the name 'JNI_CPP' but in `g++ -dynamiclib` I provided the lib name as 'libJNI_CPP' and it worked. Yeah but your load method helped me to debug the actual issue.@stark9000, @Botje